# Konva React image source does not load images from src dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, konvajs, react-konva

In React I stored base64 Konva image url to redux storage and performed first base64 image url write operation redux storage then read then image using useEffect Hook
and assigned it to react state imgSrc. For each read/write there is apply and cancel operation exists.
Each read operation is dependent on the consecutive write operation of redux but while re-rendering the component i can console log the new url.
But the problem is whenever load a new url after re-rendering the components the new image does not display in UI.
How to fix this problem?

```
const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState<any>(); 
const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
const { index, urls } = useSelector( (state: any) state.imagePointerIndexReducer ); 
const { url } = useSelector((state: any) => state.imagePointerIndexReducer); 
useEffect(() => {
 setImgSrc(urls[index]); 
},[index, urls]);

  <Stage className="konva" width={imgWidth} height={imgHeight} ref={stageRef}>
    <Layer>
      <Image image={imgSrc} offsetX={offsetX} scaleX={scaleX} brightness={contextAdjustBrightnessValue} contrast={contextAdjustContrastValue} sepia={0} opacity={1.0} hue={contextAdjustHueValue} saturation={contextAdjustStaturationValue} />
    </Layer>
  </Stage>
```

Comment: Did you have a custom `Image` component? Default `<Image />` component from `react-konva` doesn't have `imgSrc` property.

Comment: yes and ```imgSrc``` property is ```image``` property

Comment: Make a full demo please.

Comment: @lavrton Please see otherwise: `image={imgSrc}`. image is the relevant property and imgSrc is its provided value.

Answer (score 0):

Konva is not using src to draw an image. Instead you have to create and instance of `window.Image()` or `document.createElement('img') and use it as` image`attribute for`Konva.Image`.

In react, you can also use `use-image` hook to simplify the work.

```js
import { Stage, Layer, Image } from 'react-konva';
import useImage from 'use-image';

const MyImage = ({ src }) => {
  const [image] = useImage(src);
  return <Image image={image} />;
};
```